# Run and display results of python script on HTML page

Tags: python, html, embed

I have written a scraper tool in Python which when executed produces a CSV file of information. I wish to embed it in a HTML, so within the page the user is able to run it and then the results are displayed on the page from the CSV file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display the information on a website, no interaction back with your python script, all you need to do is just write the results into a HTML file and `.format()` it appropriately.

However, since this requires the user to be able to run and view the results with interaction with your python script, you would need a web server.

You could try the two most popular python based web servers that can accomplish this: [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or you could use the less common but more lightweight [Simple HTTP Server](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html).

But, do keep in mind that an easier alternative (if possible) will be to just use a GUI such as [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) or [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) or [EasyGUI](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui).